# Problems with using numpy libraries with anaconda environment on Ubuntu platform

Tags: numpy, ubuntu, anaconda

I am working on the Ubuntu platform and have downloaded the numpy libraries using the following command in the terminal:

```
>> conda install -c anaconda numpy
```

and then tried to import the numpy library as np as follows:

```
>> import numpy as np
```

now this command gives out the "ModuleNotFoundError" as follows:
[Output on the spyder console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qGat.png)

I know it looks like a basic question but I'm learning.

Thank you.

Comment: does a `conda list | grep numpy` in your environment give any results?

Answer (score -1):

You should first enter into the ipython console by 'ipython' command in terminal, then 'import numpy as np' will work.